# How to add Lenis Scroll on a specific div with VueJS

Tags: scroll, vuejs3, smooth-scrolling, custom-scrolling

I have a problem with [Lenis Scroll](https://github.com/studio-freight/lenis) on Vue3.
When I'm using it on the html tag, it works fine, no problem.

But I can't get it to work on a div/component that is further down, instead of on the html tag.

`html > body > #app > some div > #lenis-target`

According to the documentation, I am putting the following code in a `lenis.js` file, which I'm adding into the body via a script tag in`index.html`:

```
const lenis = new Lenis({
  content: document.getElementById('lenis-target')
})
function raf(time) {
    lenis.raf(time);
    requestAnimationFrame(raf);
}
requestAnimationFrame(raf);
```

But `#lenis-target` doesn't exist yet when this script is run. Doesn't work.

So I'm trying to move this lenis creation onto the mounted() of my app for instance.
It works, but if I do so, I can't call the "lenis" object anywhere anymore, with a `"lenis.stop()"` for instance.
It's returning *`lenis is not defined`* even though the div with lenis is still here in my viewport.

**My question is :**
What should I do so that I can add Lenis onto a specific div which gets mounted a few seconds after the site starts, and still be able to access the *lenis* object anywhere?

**Setup :**

- "@studio-freight/lenis": "^1.0.27"
- "vue": "^3.2.41"
- "vue-router": "^4.1.6",

Comment: initialize `lenis` variable outside of mounted hook (as null).  assign `new Lenis()` result inside mounted hook.  Now you can use it elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you yoduh, and your name fits the situation, Yo Duh